# OPTIONS method with Java client returns 200/OK always

Tags: java, rest, web-services, jersey, http-options-method

I have a Jersey REST service, which when I access using `curl` from the command line gives me the expected result:

```
$ curl -i -X OPTIONS http://localhost:7001/path/to/my/resource
HTTP/1.1 402 Payment Required
Date: Mon, 07 Aug 2017 01:03:24 GMT
...
$
```

From this, I gather that my REST service is implemented correctly.

But when I try to invoke this from a Java client, I get a `200/OK` instead.

```
public class Main3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL url = new URL("http://localhost:7001/path/to/my/resource");
        HttpURLConnection conn = null;

        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            conn.setRequestMethod("OPTIONS");
            int response = conn.getResponseCode();
            System.out.println(response);
        } finally {
            if (conn != null) {
                conn.disconnect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I stepped through the server code and the request is reaching the Jersey code in the server, but after that, it somehow returns `200/OK` without calling my Resource. What am I doing wrong here?

From debugging the server, I know that in the `org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime#process` method, the `Endpoint` chosen is `org.glassfish.jersey.server.wadl.processor.OptionsMethodProcessor.GenericOptionsInflector`. This always returns `200/OK`. Why is my resource's method annotated with `@OPTIONS` not chosen instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was that the client code does not set an `Acccept` header, and so get a default of `Accept:text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2`. `curl` instead put the header `Accept:*/*`. Jersey was routing the `curl` call to my resource because of it accepts any response, but my resource did not have the `@Produces(..)` annotation for one of those accepted by my Java client code.

The fix was to add the line:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
```

in the client code.